# elementary OS Loki Bluetooth

Tags: release-loki

I followed a link for making elementary OS better. I copied a sudo command from https://gist.github.com/memoryleakx/7567474 [HowTo Install the perfect Elementary-OS](https://gist.github.com/memoryleakx/7567474)

Basically the command was to remove the bluetooth plug switchboard. I want to know if i can undo this. I appreciate whoever takes the time to answer and hopefully resolve my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Please take caution on executing scripts from the internet the next time. Some of the commands on the link you mentioned are non-reversible such as `rm -rf`. Know the risks before executing such commands as they can potentially damage your installation permanently if executed blindly.

Comment: This script is for the version 0.2 of elementary OS as well

Comment: Your answers both helped me, i really appreciate your help! Kudos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the script, I saw these bluetooth-related commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge bluez
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/plugs/GnomeCC/gnomecc-bluetooth.plug
```

If you want bluez and has no other alternatives in mind, then you can simply reinstall with:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez
```

For the plug `/usr/lib/plugs/GnomeCC/gnomecc-bluetooth.plug`, you can reinstall with

```
sudo apt install --reinstall switchboard-plug-gcc-bluetooth
```

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative to bluez?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey please ask it on a separate question so that it can get appropriate attention :)

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Device Search window doesn't display any results.
For some reason the device results are collapsed leading the user to falsely believe no devices are being detected when in fact they are. Simply stretch the window vertically to see the results.